# Calling a method in redux middleware from a React component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am using firebase and redux in React project . while working on it i had this idea of moving all my firebase listeners to redux middlewares and than middlewares would be responsible for listening real time changes in firebase and dispatch actions to redux store . following is my test middleware

```
import firebase from "../../firebase";

const testlistener = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => async (action) => {
  // also can match regex with "/api"
  if (action.type !== "TEST_ACTION") return next(action);

  console.log("Running test Action");

  let Unsubscribe = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Test")
    .doc("testdoc")
    .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
      console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });

  next(action);
};

export default testlistener;
```

What i wanted to know is how can i unsubscribe to these changes when my component is unmounted . how can i call `Unsubscribe()` method from this middleware from my component to remove this listener

Comment: How about storing a reference in store and trigger unsubscribe action when needed?

Comment: we can not store references in store because store should always be serializable

Comment: Yeah, thats true, forgot that.

Comment: `Unsubscribe` is `firebase.firestore()...` blah blah blah, none of that looks like it needs to be in this `testListener` function. Looks like that could be defined anywhere, so in your case you can define it in the component that needs to call it, right?

Comment: @ZekeHernandez you are completely right about this firestore listener . I am just experimenting something therefore i want my listeners inside my redux middleware . that is why i want to call these methods from my components

Comment: i am trying to make a middleware that takes the payload and make listeners out of it . this way i dont have to write boilerplate Firestore listeners code in every component